# SQL double sorting directive in ORDER BY clause not working on alias

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table named `books`, listing books with category and price, which may be positive or negative (as a selling balance).
I need to select all the balances of book prices by category, sorting the result by total price with `DESC` when positive, with `ASC` when negative.

I firstly wrote this statement:

```
SELECT
    category, SUM(price) AS tot
FROM
    books
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN tot > 0 THEN tot END) DESC,
    (CASE WHEN tot <= 0 THEN tot END) ASC;
```

but the `ORDER BY` clause didn't sort as I expected.
So I replaced the alias `tot` with the `SUM(price)` expression and it worked:

```
SELECT
    category, SUM(price) AS tot
FROM
    books
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY
    (CASE WHEN SUM(price) > 0 THEN SUM(price) END) DESC,
    (CASE WHEN SUM(price) <= 0 THEN SUM(price) END) ASC;
```

Why the `ORDER BY` clause cannot work onto aliases?

And, isn't it worse from a performance perspective, given the multiple execution of the `SUM` aggregate function? Or is it cached at compile time?

Comment: Couldn't you just use `ORDER BY ABS(SUM(price)) DESC`?  Or am I missing something...

Comment: @RobEyre unfortunately not, I need the positive balances, ordered with DESC, followed by the negative balances, ordered with ASC. They are two different sorting directions, not equal to the order I would get with ABS(tot) DESC.

Comment: Ah, OK.  In that case you could bring all the positive ones to the top, then sort within using the same expression: `ORDER BY SUM(price) > 0 DESC, ABS(SUM(price)) DESC`

Comment: The two queries should produce the same result. In a small test I did, they do (https://dbfiddle.uk/1VeB-kMh). And it doesn't matter whether to use the first or the second query, they are the same to the DBMS. The sum will get eveluated only once in both cases.

Comment: Show us some sample data sorted the desired way.

Comment: (It would help to have a short example of `tot` values and how they should be ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You want the positive ones first, then the negative ones?

The first "column" in the `ORDER BY` needs to split the cases.

```
ORDER BY
    tot > 0  DESC,
    ABS(tot) DESC
```

`tot > 0` is 1 for positive values; 0 for negative

The ABS exists to make both cases use DESC.  You want the positive cases to be descending; by flipping the negative cases, they can also be DESC.